Installing Windows 2K using an external CD/DVD Drive on slightly modern hardware
I have a Windows 2k ISO on a DVD(I burned the ISO to disc) and I tried to download it using my external CD/DVD drive, but it gets stuck on the message saying something like "setup is starting Windows 2000". What is causing the problem, and is there a fix? My hardware is all from 2012-ish, and it seems like everything is going great except for that message. I would appreciate as much help as I can receive.
Edit:
I have a Intel i5-2430M CPU(64-bit, but can run non 64-bit OSes such as Win98), 16GB RAM, 600 GB HDD, and and ICH8M/ICH9M SATA RAID controller. I am trying to find Win2K-compatible drivers for it, but it's hard to find any though. I have used some non-official tools such as HSFLIP and Blackwingcat's SATA drivers. Also, I have selected Standard PC by selecting F5 when it shows a message about hardware configs, but leads me to a 0x7B error.

Is a 12 year old PC retro enough yet?

You need "F6 drivers", probably.

@Justme idk if a 12 year old PC is retro enough cause there's not a lot of info for most of the hardware.

@LeninYT 2012-ish that's like a 3rd generation 64 bit Core i (even if Pentium branded) type CPUs (Ivy/Sandy/... Bridge). At best old and useful, but not retro in any way.  Also W2k is rather borderline as well.

You need to load a Windows 2000 compatible USB 2.0(+) driver for the chipset in your computer. Unless it has a USB 1.1 port and you're willing to use that, and install with painfully slow transfer speeds. You'll also need a compatible driver for your SATA controller, or you'll have to set your SATA port mode to IDE (not RAID or AHCI).

@svin83 How could I set SATA port mode to IDE if my BIOS or anything like that doesn't show an option like that?

I don't know why this was closed as offtopic. Old operating systems are obviously definitively retrocomputing. I'd have understood if it was closed as not enough information. :) Please tell us about the system you're trying to install it on.

@knol Note, I didn't vote but do agree with that decision. The 2012 hardware is obviously way newer (possibly 64 bit) than the OS (1999, last version 2007), so it's quite clear that Win2k is not made to specified to run on later hardware. Any issue thus has a high chance being based due that hardware and it's features, which resolving is rather off topic here.

I would argue that using obsolete software is on-topic, including attempting to do so on newer systems. We have quite a few questions, that haven’t been closed, involving Windows 98 on PCs newer than 98, including a few with useful answers; it seems to me that Windows 2000 isn’t significantly less obsolete than 98. It might be harder to get running, but when did we start baulking at challenges?

However even though I think the question is on-topic, I don’t think it’s clear enough to be answerable. @LeninYT, could you please [edit] it to add more details on your specific hardware, and to mention whether you’ve looked for Windows 2000-compatible drivers for it?

From the [help], question to avoid asking: "Questions about modern, currently supported computers are off-topic. This includes questions about earlier versions of a current machine or OS." And I see Win2K as an earlier version of modern Windows. Not to mention the hardware, which is newer than the PC I'm using regularly with an up-to-date Linux.

ObMeta: Are questions about Windows 2000 on-topic for this site?, Change rule preventing "questions about earlier versions of a current machine or OS"?

@LeninYT If there’s no IDE mode then you'll probably need a SATA/Chipset driver for the installer to recognize your drives.
